# Please make the "favorites" tab sortable in the SEDE

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

*Ext: of course the best would be if it would be so nicely sortable/searchable like the questions on the ordinary sites.*

Currently the only way to remark "my" queries is to favorize them.

However, as far I can see, they are ordered on their creation time. People having a lot of queries will have troubles to find them.

Ideally, it could be extended making them also taggable, but I think it would be likely out of your priorities.

But ordering the favorites by the name of the query, it would be likely a trivial work. Actually, I could have made it long ago in the form of a pull request, but I am not very good in .net .

Comment: They are ordered descending on the id of the votes table, as seen [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Controllers/UserController.cs#L312). I'm not sure if I'm a big fan of simply changing existing behavior. I would rather have sort options then or a new tab with the sort you propose. The latter seems the easiest to implement but UX wise it will look clumsy with two favorites tabs, one for the existing sort and one for the sort on `Title`.

Comment: @rene Thanks, I can see it. Well, maybe then making the ordering selectable... uhmm... it seems I need to learn this thingy... :-(